# Mathematical multiple lines inside a parbox

Tags: math-mode

I am getting multiple errors for missing `}` or missing `$` inside a parbox with two lines, but I do not understand for the life of me why... I have put together a MWE replicating exactly what the problem is.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\def\df{\rule{0pt}{1.8ex}}

\begin{document}
\Large
\raisebox{+20.0pt}{%
  \fboxrule=2pt%
  \fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
    \parbox[t][4.0cm]{8.0cm}{%
      \addvspace{0.5cm}\centering
      {\boldmath\color{blue}
      $\displaystyle
      {x} \;=\; -\, \frac{1}{k \,-\, 1}\,x_{\df{1}} \,+\,
      \frac{k}{k \,-\, 1}\,x_{\df{2}}
      $}\\[0.5cm]
      {\boldmath\color{blue}
      $\displaystyle
      {y} \;=\; -\, \frac{1}{k \,-\, 1 }\,y_{\df{1}} \,+\,
      \frac{k}{ k \,-\, 1 }\,y_{\df{2}}
      $}%
    }%
  }%
}%end raisebox
\;\;\textbf{.}
\end{document}
```

Here are the errors:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.23 }
      %end raisebox
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }

l.23 }
      %end raisebox
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.23 }
      %end raisebox
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.23 }
      %end raisebox
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Comment: The MWE you posted compiles fine for me. No errors.

Comment: @Diegis The code provided compiles and produces a blue box enclosing two blue formulas. If you could present the errors you obtain maybe further assistance can be provided.

Comment: The posted document has no errors but it is bad style to use `$\displaystyle` it would be much better to use a multi line display environment such as `align` or `multline`

Comment: I have posted the error above (there were not enough characters for it in a comment).

Comment: The trouble is, you haven't posted the code responsible for those errors. You've posted code which compiles fine. Can you create an MWE which produces those errors when you compile it and post that?

Comment: I did, the code that creates those errors is at the top -- I understand that this exact code does not produce an error on your machine, but it does on mine. No idea why, and your answer makes it even more baffling. It must be something to do with my environment then, my MikTex or maybe even TeXnicCenter.

Answer (score 2):

You have too much manual markup: there's very rarely need for `\;` and `\,` sometimes is useful, but not in your use case.

Use `aligned` provided by `amsmath`. I also added `\bfrac` to match the fraction line with the thickness of the minus sign. In order to lower a subscript, use an empty superscript.

The strange `border` setting is to work around something that seems to be a bug of `standalone`; 7pt is half `\fboxsep` plus `\fboxrule`.

```
\documentclass[border={-7pt 0 0 0}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}

\newcommand{\bfrac}[2]{%
  \genfrac{}{}{0.6pt}{}{#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
  \boldmath\color{blue}%
  $\!\begin{aligned}
   x &= - \bfrac{1}{k-1}x^{}_{1} + \bfrac{k}{k-1}x^{}_{2}
   \\
   y &= - \bfrac{1}{k-1}y^{}_{1} + \bfrac{k}{k-1}y^{}_{2}
  \end{aligned}$%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know a lot of people are against manual markup, but I want my expressions to be extremely readable after being correct. The signs (= + -) are crowding the rest of the expression too much for my liking, plus there is not enough space between fractions and multiplicands. And I found no better way to control this -- anyway, this should not have anything to do with the syntax, it is just a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

Use the default math expression with `\[ ... \]`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}

{\Large\fboxrule=2pt\fboxsep=10pt
\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\[ x = -\frac{ 1 }{ k - 1 }\,x_1 + \frac{ k }{ k - 1 }\,x_2 \]
\[ y = -\frac{ 1 }{ k - 1 }\,y_1 + \frac{ k }{ k - 1 }\,y_2 \]
\end{varwidth}}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]